# Does 'import' in JavaScript fetch the whole file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module, export

I am wondering about the practical use of 'importing' a .js file at the front end.

Say, we have a file module.js:

```
// module.js
export var a = 10;
var b = 20;
```

Now when we do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script type="module">
    import {a} from "./module.js";
</script>
</body></html>
```

Does variable b get fetched over the internet and only discarded at the front end?

If variable b is discarded at the back end, how can the server tell what is needed and what is not?

If variable b is discarded at the front end, why don't we just do the following?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script src="./module.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: "*If variable b is discarded at the front end, why don't we just do the following?*" why would you want that at all?

Comment: @VLAZ That is what I am wondering -- whether there is ever a need to import a .js file.

Comment: Importing from a module and just splatting everying in the global scope is...rather different. Why would you want to do the latter? Considering all the time and effort people have spent coming up with various ways to *avoid it like the plague*. What is the benefit to drop over a decade of web practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you run that code in a browser, the entire file is transmitted across the network, parsed, and instantiated. That said, in both scripts and modules, the JavaScript engine may be able to identify dead code (like that `b` variable and its initialization) and discard it, **if** it seems worth the runtime cost of doing so, which it rarely is.

**However**, most *bundlers* (Webpack, Parcel, etc.) offer optional *tree-shaking* features they can apply to modules when building bundles. They do static analysis on the modules being bundled together and identify things that are definitely "dead wood" (hence "tree-shaking") and leave that code out of the bundle.